# PHP - third party rest call, wait for response, prevent reload

Tags: php, design-patterns

I've got a logic problem.
Application is in php, written by me.
There's a form where the user enters some data and press a button to submit. I know the Post/Redirect/Get pattern to prevent the site reload.
In my case when the user press the button im talking with a third party rest api and need to wait for an response to store it in a database. So I cant close the current form till I've got my reponse. The response taking 5-10seconds.

Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Make the call to the external system a *"job"*. Submitting the form adds the job to a job queue (which can also deduplicate identical jobs), and then redirect/gets immediately to a status page where the status of this job can be seen. The job is handled by a *background worker* and the result written to a database of some sort. When the job has completed, the client can continue with the next step in the process. — A queue/worker setup isn't exactly PHP's forte or standard MO, but it's entirely doable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your idea. I will research this.